# How to display an image or file in c# without copying it to application(resources)?

Tags: c#, .net

I am new in c# and i really love it but i wanna know if i add a file(for example an image file) to my project and if do not copy it to application folder how can i use it?
For example the name of file is file.jpg and i write this event handler for a button:

```
picturebox1.image=image.FromFile(@"file.jpg") 
    // it won't show me because it is not copied to app folder.
```

How to use it without copying?

Comment: Try with using a full path to the image, ie. "C:\where\Ìhave\MyPicture\file.jpg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you must distribute the picture somehow. It can be as a resource (the picture will then be copied into the exe) or as contents (the file will be copied into the app's folder).

If you use the Contents solution, you should not assume that the current directory is the directroy of the application. You should then write something like:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Path.Combine(
  Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath),
  "file.jpg");
```

Otherwise, you'll have to know the full path of the image file.